# How to hide contact details of seller only for specific 12 hour period from 9am to 9pm

Tags: php

I have created a page where buyer can contact seller

```
 <span> Seller Contact Number </span>: <?php echo $this->prodDet->mobile; ?>
```

However - also want to restrict in that the contact number of seller can not be shown from 9pm to 9am for 12 hours

Unable to get in how to implement the code using php using time zone as per IST
Pls advise how to perform the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set default time zone for IST so date function will return your local time. Then use `date` function of php to get current hour.

Use of 24hr format is good to use. Use this hour value to check if time is less than 9pm and grater than 9am to show contact details.

Check below code that will help you.

```
<?php
/* set time zone*/
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

$hour = date("H"); //get current hour in 24hr format
if($hour <= '21' && $hour >= '9'):
?>    
<span> Seller Contact Number </span>: <?php echo $this->prodDet->mobile; ?>
<?php endif;?>
```